# extract tables from webpage into csv file using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am very new in python and currently learning pandas toolkit and I want to extract table data from the web page for my following project
can anyone help me by providing the best toolkit name for data extraction and less time consuming as I am not focusing on that part.Thank you.
http://contentlinks.dionglobal.in/ib/closeprices.asp?Exchange=NSE&Startname=A

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('http://contentlinks.dionglobal.in/ib/closeprices.asp?Exchange=NSE&Startname=A')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text)
table = soup.findAll('table')
tr = table[-1].findAll('tr')
for i in tr:
    # here you can extract data from tr
    # and write your pandas code
    print i  # example
    print '\n\n'  # example
```

I am not sure, in which way you want to save, but this will help

Comment: actually, i want the data(open price,close price) of individual stock prices into CSV file web page class name=alternate,alternate1, and thank you so much for your help